# Web farm Session get saved in Load balancer server WP or web server WP

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-farm, inproc

Was reading one article and got confuse with this point.

In Web farm, one Application is hosted in multiple server right , and they are connected with Virtual IP address with Load balancer. And Load balancer IP address is exposed to world, so Client send request to Load balancer and based on traffic it distributed the call to corresponding web server.

This is what we are doing in our APP , we have LB2na.abc.com as Load balancer and server1.abc.com & server2.abc.com as web server.

Now question is, we save session in INPROC right, so session save inside worker process.
Let say User open submission form, and as per traffic request went to server1, session variable got saved in worker process of server1. Now Users click on Submit, by this time traffic is high so request got in server2, so what happen to session variable.

So In Web farm Session get saved in Load balancer server WP or web server WP